# Plotting $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt[]{-N}]$ as a lattice in $\mathbb{C}$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, graphing-functions

$\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-N}]=\left\{a+b\sqrt[]{-N}:a,b\in \mathbb{Z}, N\geq 1\right\}$

(note that $N$ is a fixed natural number)

I was curious how one would plot this as a lattice in $\mathbb{C}$

For example, if $N=1$, I know we get the Gaussian integers and we form a bunch of dots at all the integer coordinates

My question is when $N\neq 1$. Would we change the imaginary axis?

For example, I am not sure how one would plot $2+\sqrt[]{-3}$

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$2+\sqrt{-3}$ can be corresponded to $2+\sqrt{3}i$ in the complex plane.
So we can identify $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-3}]$ to be $\{a+b\sqrt{3}i \mid a,b\in \mathbb{Z}\}$. When we plot these points on the complex plane, we obtain a rectangular lattice, with a basis given by $\{1,\sqrt{3}i\}$.

Similar things can be done for $\mathbb{Z}[-N]$, the lattice will be rectangular unless $N=1$.

Comment: So for the example when $N=3$, we may have points on the complex plane whose coordinates are not necessarily integers? Example: a=1,b=1, you would plot a point at (1,$\sqrt[]{3})$?

Comment: @northcity4, yes exactly

Answer (score 0):

Consider the identification: 
$$a+bi=\left(\begin{array}{cc}
a&-b\\
b&a
\end{array}\right)
$$

Then this gives you a natural change of $\mathbb{Z}$-basis, and you can view the plot of your lattice in $\mathbb{C}$ that way.